# Pandas: соединить строки с дублями в отдельном столбце

Tags: pandas, excel

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно в Pandas соединить (сложить) строки, с одинаковыми значениями в одном столбце. Это мой первый проект! =)

Это ввод
[image: Ввод]

Это вывод
[image: Это вывод]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7060/178576)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: groupby() и sum()

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался, всё получилось!